# htacess - переадресация виртуальных ссылок с отловом гет параметров

Tags: php, .htaccess

Приветствую друзья.
Есть одностраничный сайт, где единственная страница index.php
генерирует контент и каталог и генерирует адресную строку вложений каталога

Если пользователь хочет сохранить строку что бы открыть потом
вот строка:

site.com/transport/motobike/?mototype=2;3&valueengine=1;2

Мне нужно что бы это всё дело переадресовалось на index.php, и на этой странице можно было поймать запрос пользователя:

"/transport/motobike/?mototype=2;3&valueengine=1;2"

что бы можно было уже сгенерировать для него нужный контент.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Ну и обрабатывайте всё, что передали в q
И $_GET параметры полностью сохраняются. Так же доступны через $_REQUEST

Comment: Признателен за ответ. Сейчас проверю и отпишусь о результате.

Comment: p.s: а вообще язык в htacess - ну просто ужас какой сложный для понимания.

Comment: Язык не сложный.   
Просто нужно потренироваться.   
Запомнить основные переменные, условия и научиться составлять регулярки.